# Deploying a release app on an actual phone

Tags: java, android, installation

I'm just having a new problem. All my Android applications, which are perfectly functional in the emulator, alsofail to install on my phone.

A few weeks ago, I had no problem deploying these applications. The only thing changed in the meantime is the Java version (I have updated to 1.7).

I have tried to :
       - re-create my keystore,
       - uninstall the previous version from the phone before trying to install the new one

but the problem still remains...

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: did you receive some error message?

Comment: Android support jdk 1.4 - 1.6. Not sure it's the problem though.

Comment: No error message. The phone only says that the application has not been installed.

Comment: I will try to rebuild my application with jdk 1.6. Hope it will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Android SDK still does not support java 7. Try to change project properties so it compiles against java JDK 5 or 6.

1. Right click on your project and select "Propertie",
2. Then select "Java Compiler"
3. Check "Enable project specific settings"
4. Select 1.5 or 1.6 from "Compiler compliance settings".

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I have turned back to JDK 6 and everything is fine now.